# What kind of power adapter do I need in New Zealand

Tags: power, new-zealand

We will be traveling in New Zealand for 9 months.  What is the best adapter to get for our laptops, Kindle, iPad and iPhones?

Comment: What kind of plugs do your devices already have? And what kinds of voltages do they already accept?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

New Zealand uses 230V  and [AS/NZS 3112](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AS_3112) plug:

[image: plug]

You need to check first that all your chargers support also 230V (iDevices chargers normally are 100-240V) after you need a travel adapter, like this one:

[Skross World Travel Adaptor 3](http://amzn.to/1t3zCD4)

Because you will stay 9 months, for your iPad and iPhone you can consider buy in New Zealand the [Apple 12W USB Power adapter](http://store.apple.com/nz/product/MD836X/A/apple-12w-usb-power-adapter), it is able to charge several Apple devices.

Comment: If you are bringing a lot of devices, bring a small power bar that works with your home plugs. Plug the power bar into the adapter and your existing chargers and devices into the power bar.

Comment: What I've done if I'm going for a long time to another country is buying a power bar in my own country and in arrival just buya cheap plug and connect the two.